# Do all of the distortions in the space caused by that object get lost? Or do the distortions get back to where they began?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime

According to general relativity, if an object keeps moving and warping space and then gets lost by entering a black hole, do all of the distortions in the space caused by that object get lost? Or do the distortions get back to where they began?

There is an answer by "Navid" that says it is possible for the distortions that happened in space by the object to disappear.

Well, first of all, my imagination says that space will keep warping if an object keeps moving. Meaning that the peak of the distortion keeps increasing; now if there is a case where the distortions will disappear, then wouldn't this come to mind that a new black hole would happen because there is a loss of space? By new black hole, I mean the disappeared or lost space between the destination black hole and the beginning position of the object. My other imagination is that when objects move in space, they carry the space with themselves and don't keep stretching or warping the space.

Answer (score 1):

It's like the way you create ripples on the surface of a pool by moving your finger. If you stop moving your finger, or remove it from the pool, then the ripples it caused will propagate outwards from where the finger was when you removed it. They diminish in amplitude as they go. Similar statements apply to distortions in spacetime associated with massive bodies: when a body falls to a black hole then the distortions (called gravitational waves) propagate outwards, with diminishing amplitude as they go. The ones caused close to the black hole horizon will be partly pulled back towards that horizon. Those that are not pulled back will have greatly diminished amplitude and slowed down evolution, as they originate from nearer to the horizon.

Comment: The way I understood your answer is that you are saying that "gravitational waves" are the same as space. They are not different things that happen inside the space. Is that right?

Comment: To answer your question would require a careful definition of what is meant by the term "space". The most common way to present the mathematics is to say that gravitational waves are waves of spacetime itself. However you can if you like also interpret the mathematics another way, in which spacetime is fixed and the gravitational field is a field existing in spacetime whose effects are the same as if spacetime changed.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the particle's mass is much smaller than the black hole's mass $m\ll M$, it will not affect the geometry of the black hole's exterior. Then we can think of the particle moving on a fixed background.

   After the particle is swallowed by the black hole, we will get a black hole with mass $M+m\approx M$. The distortion disappears and the geometry is the same as before (up to corrections of order $m/M$).
2. However, if the particle's mass is comparable to that of a black hole, the geometry changes drtastically. In other words, the distortion doesn't go away.

$\bullet$ The first case ($m\ll M$) can be described by linearizing Einstein's equations.
However, the second one requires treating the equations non-linearly.

Comment: The first case is similar to the quasi-normal mode of a black hole (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.2975.pdf). An example of the second scenario is a binary black hole. ie. ; A system consisting of two black holes in close orbit around each other (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_black_hole)